# XQuery resulting in Out Of Memory Error

Tags: xquery, basex

Following is the XML file -

```
<Info>
  <Name>
    <P1>Tomy</P1>
    <P2>John</P2>
    <R>P2</R>
  </Name>
  <Name>
    <P1>Tomy</P1>
    <P2>John</P2>
    <R>P1</R>
  </Name>
  <Name>
    <P1>Rojer</P1>
    <P2>Messi</P2>
    <R>P2</R>
  </Name>
  <Name>
    <P1>Messi</P1>
    <P2>Carl</P2>
    <R>P2</R>
  </Name>
  <Name>
    <P1>Messi</P1>
    <P2/>
    <R>P1</R>
  </Name>

</Info>
```

`P1` is the Player No 1 and `P2` is the Player No 2, `R` is the result of the match.
I want to list the names of Players in following format, with distinct occurences.

```
<P>Tomy V John</P>
<P>Rojer V Messi</P>
<P>Messi V John</P>
<P>Messi</P>
```

Following is the solution, which gives the desired output -

```
let $o := doc('sam')//Name
for $x in $o
  let $p := if (string-length($x/P2/text()) > 0) then concat($x/P1/text(),' Vs. ',$x/P2/text()) else $x/P1/text()
  for $y in $p
    group by $y
    order by $y
    return <a>{$y}</a>
```

But this query works better only for some selected records. In actual, I have 200000+ records, and when I execute this query, I get Out Of Memory Error. I am using BaseX 7.6.

If I remove the `group by` clause, the executes without error, but it gives the wrong result ie; with duplicate values. I need distinct result.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  for $x in doc('sam')//Name
  let $p := if (string-length($x/P2/text()) > 0) then concat($x/P1/text(),' Vs. ',$x/P2  /text()) else $x/P1/text()
  group by $p
  order by $p
  return <a>{$p}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain why I was getting OOM ?

Comment: @John You simply have a lot of entries in memory. You can also increase the memory for BaseX by starting with the -Xmx=1024mb (or whatever value seems appropriate) option.

Comment: @dirkk Yes that can be definitely done, but what I think is I complicated the situation using 2 `let` and 2 'for`. The query in the answer is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking in this question, a possible solution for an out of memory behavior could be also a wrapping xml tag and the specific behavior of copying new nodes related to xQuery implementation e.g:

```
... <a>{$y}</a>
```

In that case something like this could also be the solution:

```
let $o := doc('sam')//Name
for $x in $o
  let $p := if (string-length($x/P2/text()) > 0) then concat($x/P1/text(),' Vs. ',$x/P2/text()) else $x/P1/text()
  for $y in $p
    group by $y
    order by $y
    return (# db:copynode false #) { <a>{$y}</a> }
```

For more please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48887745/4825622